# Safari 15 on Mac always opens the homepage when I try to open a link in a new tab

Tags: safari

I just updated Safari to Version 15.0 on my MacBook. Unfortunately, opening a link in a new tab doesn't work properly. At first, it seems to try to load it, but then quickly redirects to the homepage. It doesn't matter if I try to open a link while holding the cmd key or via right-click. But opening a link in a new window works just fine.

Is it already a known bug? Are there ways to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably encounter this issue if you have selected the option to use cmd to open a link in a new tab in the preferences of Safari. Removing this option and then reselecting it seems to solve this issue.

Comment: I think I'm having the same problem (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428557/with-tab-groups-in-safari-15-opening-in-new-tab-creates-blank-tab). Unfortunately this solution didn't resolve my issue. Any other ideas to try? I unchecked the setting, restarted safari, then re-checked the setting.

Comment: Does it work if you open a tab via right-click? Maybe you want to try resetting Safari (https://support.intego.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003863692-How-To-Reset-Your-Safari-Web-Browser). If that doesn't work, then I can only suggest reinstalling macOS. But take it as a last resort if there are no other solutions as I'm just your average Safari user. You might also want to wait for the official release of macOS Monterey which should happen very soon (I expect it this month where we'll probably have another apple event). Maybe updating your operating system will solve this issue.