# With Tab Groups in Safari 15, opening in new tab creates blank tab

Tags: macos, safari, tabs

The new Safari 15 Tab Groups are helping my browser tabs stay organized. I'm liking it.

However, more often than not, opening a link in a new tab (command + click a link, or even trying to open a Google Doc in Drive) opens the new tab but it's empty. The content fails to load, and I just see my Start Page.

1. In a Tab Group, browse to [macrumors.com](https://macrumors.com)
2. Command click the first articles's title

Notice how the new tab opens (with the proper url showing in the tab), but the actual tab is blank, and just shows the Start Page.

Any idea how to fix this? Unfortunately this kind of makes tab groups unusable for me, since I use Google Drive all the time and I can't open documents easily.

I've tried [this solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/427789/safari-15-on-mac-always-opens-the-homepage-when-i-try-to-open-a-link-in-a-new-ta) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I've passing by the same problem. What I reach as a trigger to this problem is have multiple Safari window opened.

So, when I left only one window opened, the links opened on new tabs now work just fine.

Comment: thanks. that's my experience now, too. whenever a blank tab opens, I just have to go and close other windows. still a bug, but at least we have a workaround now